# Inconsistent declaration of `ndarray.__array_ufunc__`

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

While writing an ndarray subclass, Mypy flags a problem related to the declaration of the `method` argument in `__array_ufunc__`.

The [`__array_ufunc__` docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html#array-ufunc-for-ufuncs) say:

- *method* is a string indicating how the Ufunc was called, either
  `"__call__"` to indicate it was called directly, or one of its methods:
  `"reduce"`, `"accumulate"`, `"reduceat"`, `"outer"`, or `"at"`.

Which is consistent with the [ufunc methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#methods) documentation.

However, Numpy declares [`__array_ufunc__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/284a2f09bf304ea6a98cc1ad2f3dfc4c203b3c93/numpy/__init__.pyi#L1468) as:

```
def __array_ufunc__(
    self,
    ufunc: ufunc,
    method: L["__call__", "reduce", "reduceat", "accumulate", "outer", "inner"],
    *inputs: Any,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> Any: ...
```

Method `"at"` is missing, replaced by a mysterious `"inner"`, which is not an ufunc method.

Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like an error to me. Probably didn't get noticed because people have been annotating that argument as `str` when they override the method, and because the actual calls to the method occur in C code that doesn't get type-checked.